# How can I create an html file from a php file?

Tags: php, bash

For my static html I want to keep a large file that I can send all at once.  In this case `module.2.Mega.php` ... How can I use php from the command line to output the HTML for this file to `module.2.Mega.htm` ?

I'm in a bash shell

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body id="body">
    <?php include 'module.2.Mega.php';?>
  </body>
</html>
```

after creating the HTML file, I would then have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body id="body">
    <?php include 'module.2.Mega.htm';?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not make it `module.2.Mega.php`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use php from the command line to output the HTML for this
>   file to module.2.Mega.htm

```
php module.2.Mega.php > module.2.Mega.htm
```

Comment: `module.2.Mega.htm` will be a static file with the processed code from  `module.2.Mega.php`

Answer (score 0):

you can write the PHP code inside the HTML page instead of having one page .PHP and another .HTML